# How to access handles of another MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have two GUIs in MATLAB. I stored some values in GUI1 in the handles structure, so that when it displays in the Command Window, it looks like this:

```
        GUI1: [1x1 Figure]
        pushbutton2: [1x1 UIControl]
              text2: [1x1 UIControl]
              edit1: [1x1 UIControl]
             output: [1x1 Figure]
              val1: 0
```

I want to use `val1` to set a value, `counter`, in GUI2. I don't have any command to initialize `counter` in GUI2. How do I access the handles of GUI1 in GUI2?

I tried to use the command guidata(findobj('Tag', 'GUI1')) to get those handles, but it shows me that it's empty.

I tried doing the following:

In GUI1, under OpeningFcn:

```
handles.val1 = 0;
guidata(hObject, handles);
setappdata(handles.GUI1,'val1', handles.val1)
```

And in GUI2, in a pushbutton function:

```
counter = getappdata(handles.GUI1,'val1')
```

But that doesn't seem to work either! It gives me an error saying, "Reference to non-existent field 'GUI1'."

I have the handle visibility on for GUI1, and a tag set to "GUI1". Why am I still having this issue?

Comment: Maybe try `counter=findobj('type','double')`, or `counter=findobj('type','double','parent',GUI1)`

Comment: It says: 0x0 empty GraphicsPlaceholder array.

Comment: Or maybe with [setappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html?refresh=true) and [getappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html?searchHighlight=getappdata)?

Comment: @Benoit_11 I just added that to my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the GUI's Tag before finding object, i.e GUI1's Tag = `GUI1`. Then you can try to find all children of root object:

```
gui1_H = get(0,'Children', 'Tag', 'GUI1');
```

or just use `findobj`:

```
gui1_H = findobj('Type', 'figure', 'Tag', 'GUI1');
```

In some cases, the GUI's `HandleVisibility` is set to `off`, in this case, you can use `findall` in your GUI2:

```
gui1_H = findall(0, 'Type', 'figure', 'Tag', 'GUI1');
```

And get the handle struct:

```
data = guidata(gui1_H);
disp(data.val);
```

Note that you are currently opening 2 GUIs at the same time, so if you keep both GUIs' default Tag to be `figure1`, then `gui1_H` will not be counted as graphic object's handle, hence you also cannot get its `guidata`.

Comment: I haven't tried this as yet, as I managed to compress everything into one GUI, but I'll take a shot at it for any future use, and let you know!

Comment: just note that it is quite important to set tags, it helps you find anything later